# Run script on current page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run a script on a page that I'm currently using instead of using `driver.get("url")` that opens a different anonymous tab everytime.

The issue is that I want to run the script in a page that I'm logged in, not log everytime I run the program.

Is it possible?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do, can you provide steps?

Comment: and post your current code please

Comment: i think you also need to learn about pytest, i would create a setup class separately where you launch browser, maximize screen and log to the page, yield,  then all my test cases in other class that will inherit the setup class, so all the test cases will be executed without having to launch url and log into the app, everytime

Comment: There's no exact code. I want to run a script using selenium on the current page I'm browsing without having to user .get()

Comment: I don't believe what you're asking is possible, if I understand you correctly. Webdriver spins up a separate instance of the browser to run the tests. You cannot make it connect to an existing browser session, as far as I know.